# Install AMD HD 6400M / 7400m drivers

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, amd-graphics

How to install AMD drivers for above mentioned graphic card in Kubuntu 16.04 LTS 
Here is the info that may be needed to help.

`vasu@vasu-PC:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] password for vasu: 
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free`

`vasu@vasu-PC:~$ sudo lspci -vvnn | grep VGA

        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-

        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+

        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Intel VGA Compatible Controller
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
vasu@vasu-PC:~$`

How can I set switchable graphic setting like windows in Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appear to be there's no compatibility at all for any ubuntu version 16.04 LTS or other since I remember that was for the reason I gave up Linux for the first time and returned to classic Windows 7 and 10 :( sadly!

But good news! Kubuntu or any Ubuntu version 18.04 + came with the new AMD open source drivers automatically installed by default.

Since I have the exactly same AMD HD 6400M / 7400m as yours. I'm initiating an investigation on it and would love to learn more about it.

I believe it's not necessary to switch the graphics between AMD and Intel because I remember doing that in the past and only after learnt that was not necessary, it's a whole another process and doesn't involve installing the graphics but messing a little bit with Ubuntu.

My best advice is to install Ubuntu 18.04 because it's much better than 16.04 and I can only guarantee that and at same time you are going to have the new drivers already installed.

Another part of this history I already had contacted AMD a year ago for only they tell me that they ***WILL NOT*** ***provide any new drivers*** ***for Linux*** and somehow ***they did*** provided because a lot people was revolted for having AMD adapters without support and after that they release the code somehow. Now you have the drivers but only for new  or supported Linux versions.

It's up to you!